# How to cut everything before specific characters

Tags: java, regex, trim

Good Morning,
I'm new in Java and I'd like to cut this String:

```
"jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb"
```

into this:

```
"testdb"
```

I've tryed it with `regex`, but how I said, I'm new and I don't know the Syntax of regex very good. I tried something like this:

```
databaseName = databaseName.replaceAll("*.:", "");
System.out.println(databaseName);
```

It would be glad if someone could help me. Thank you for your answers

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html get `lastIndexOf(":")` and `substring()` it from that position +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know you only what everything after the last `:` then you can simply use

```
databaseName = databaseName.substring(databaseName.lastIndexOf(":") + 1)
```

Of course you should make sure it actually contains the delimiter...

```
if (databaseName.contains(":")) {...
```

You could also use `String#split` and grab the elements you want...

```
String parts[] = databaseName.split(":");
String name = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Comment: @user3734011 Hope it helps. Remember, there's more than one way to skin this fish, use what makes sense for you

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] str = yourString.split(":");
//str[str.length -1] is your answer.
```

Answer (score 2):

As @MadProgrammer said in his comment, *"there's more than one way to skin this fish..."*.

If you wish *to skin this fish* using `regex`, This will work:

```
databaseName = databaseName.replaceAll(".*(?=:)?:","");
```